# How to use zclip in MySql loop

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Im trying to copy data to clipboard using zclip jquery. problem that im facing is when i copy it will copy everything in the database in field "name". but what i want is to copy a single name that user clicked. if the click another copy that. not the whole thing. can anyone tell me how to do this. thanks.

this is the zclip code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('p#copy').zclip({
path:'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
copy:function(){return $('div#copy').text();}
});
```

MySQL loop:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM names ORDER BY id desc";
$result= mysql_query($query) or die ('Mysql Error');
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo  '<div id="copy">'.$row['name'].'</div>';
echo  '<p id="copy">copy</p>';
}
```

zclip site: http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML you generate is not valid which is hindering you in the end to achieve the result you're looking for: in HTML an ID can only be used once (see: [Element identifiers: the id and class attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)). You are using the same ID for multiple DIVs. That can not work, as an ID must be *unique* across the whole HTML document.

Instead assign one ID to each DIV (e.g. by using a counter) and then apply the jquery function on the specific DIV only.

```
$idCounter = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $idCounter++;
    echo  '<div id="copy-div-', $idCounter, '">', $row['name'], '</div>';
    echo  '<p id="copy-p-', $idCounter, '" class="copy-click">copy</p>';
}
```

*Code-Example:* Create multiple IDs with a counter variable

Comment: thank but how can i do the same to javascript? because javascript also have to get the correct id right?